# Spontaneous breaking of a discrete non-Abelian symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry-breaking

Can someone give an example of an one dimensional local gapped quantum lattice model with a discrete non-Abelian global internal symmetry that is spontaneously broken in the ground state? In particular, where ground states transform as an irreducible representation with dimension > 1?